# How could I recover a file from Recycle Bin with CMD?

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

I have a file in $Recycle.Bin which its metadata points out a non-existent drive on the system and a path - `.......E.:.\.D.e.s.k.t.o.p.\.F.i.l.e...t.x.t` how could I potentially recover that File.txt using CMD or Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Recycle Bin applet and right-click the file `File.txt` and select "Cut".

Then open Explorer, navigate to the destination folder, right-click any
empty space and select "Paste" (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

You should now have recovered the file inside this folder.

Comment: Note: I don't think this can be done with CMD.

Comment: Should be possible using CMD as the $RECYCLE.BIN folder is on every computer. That is the folder where the files are stored, though the filenames are encrypted, but in theory it is possible to just restore all. But using the GUI is much easier anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/moving-files-in-recyclebin-with-cmd/d7220223-7ef7-456b-86e2-f42eb04e3502), there is a userRecycleBin folder in the c: root directory.

```
c:\> cd C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5 <tab>

c:\> dir
08.04.2021  09:12               104 $I6DZQ91.mp4
06.04.2021  11:29               162 $I6SSCZL.lnk
02.04.2021  01:55               118 $I7I5YC2.exe
08.04.2021  18:40               198 $I8AC6Q8.lnk
07.04.2021  14:12               110 $I9PJOBM.exe
08.04.2021  06:12               194 $I935TQX.mp4
```

The recycle bin contains separate bins for the various users. When auto completing "S-1-5" you will need to find your user's folder. If you get access denied, try another one. Once you have yours, you can move the files back. Unfortunately the names are a bit mangled.